# Streamreader Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working with StreamReader in my Asp.Net mvc application.

I'm having an issue getting the StreamReader to use the root of my application, and not the C:// drive on my machine.

I have the following:

```
 public ActionResult Test()
            {
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
                TextReader textReader;
                textReader = new StreamReader("../Content/items.xml");
                Test test = (Test)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);
                textReader.Close();
                return View(test);
            }
```

Comment: `I'm having an issue getting .....`, Will you post your *issue* or should we try to guess it?

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: I'm having an issue getting the StreamReader to use the root of my application, and not the C:// drive on my machine.

Comment: I Don't see anything remotely close to the code referencing the `C` drive as you have stated.. also if you are not familiar with reading the contents from a level down then look up `~` and how to use it.. also research `Server.MapPath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a web application, the current working directory of the process isn't the directory containing your source code. You might want to look at [`HttpServerUtility.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath) or [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath).

Note that this doesn't really have anything to do with `StreamReader` - for diagnostic purposes, you'd be better off with something like:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("../Content/items.xml");
Debug.WriteLine(file.FullName);
```